# Calling methods in ActiveJob perform

Tags: ruby, rails-activejob

I'm getting a `No Method Error` when calling my job. I don't know why. This is the actual error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get_customers' for #
<GetCustomersJob:0x007f15280e4270>
```

I'm learning `ActiveJob` and created my first job that is super simple, and calls a method defined on my `Shop` model. The job looks like this:

```
class GetCustomersJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(current_shop)
    current_shop.get_customers.perform
  end
end
```

`get_customers` is defined on my shop model just fine, and `current_shop` is a `Shop` model object. `get_customers` works as expected outside of this job. I just can't seem to get it to work within this job.

I also tried:

```
Shop.current_shop.get_customers.perform
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the `perform` method - in there you just want to perform something, in your case you want to call `get_customers` on the `current_shop` object. So do that.

```
class GetCustomersJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(current_shop)
    current_shop.get_customers # removed .perform
  end
end
```

Later, you want to call the job. To do that you write the job's class name and use either `perform_now` to run the job immediately:

```
GetCustomersJob.perform_now(Shop.current_shop)
```

or `perform_later` to queue the job for later:

```
GetCustomersJob.perform_later(Shop.current_shop)
```

Comment: Yea, still getting the exact same error. I updated the OP, but its saying `get_customers` is not defined on the `job`. Thats true, its defined on the model. And I pass in a `Shop` object to work on.. hence my confusion

Comment: @ToddT I am very curious if you've found the cause of the error?

Comment: It ended up being that my code was fine, I wasn't restarting Sidekiq, so my code changed weren't being picked up.. Lesson learned! Thanks for the help

Comment: @ToddT True, sidekiq needs to be restarted anytime code changes.

Comment: @ToddT though I doubt this `current_shop.get_customers.perform` is correct... (I say it is wrong)

Comment: Yep you are right.. I did take out `perform` so I marked your answer as correct. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to name the test class with `Test` at the end, so `perform_now` was not defined.

(writing this for future me :wave:)

Comment: :facepalm: I did the same, thanks!